# Maximum discount percent magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

How to configure the maximum discount percent in magento for the cart amount.

Example: Cart value is 3,50,000

Coupon Code discount applicable : 20%

Discount applicable 70,000

However I want to limit this to 50,000 only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i apply coupon code if order total value is greater than 100 INR?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147442/how-can-i-apply-coupon-code-if-order-total-value-is-greater-than-100-inr)

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, this is not possible in the Magento 1.x without an extension or code modification.

To add this feature in our module we had to:

1) add a new field `max_discount` in the table `salesrule`

2) observe event `salesrule_validator_process`

```
        <salesrule_validator_process>
        <observers>
            <amasty_rules_model_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>amrules/observer</class>
                <method>handleValidation</method>
            </amasty_rules_model_observer>
        </observers>
        </salesrule_validator_process>
```

3) keep track of all discounts given to item by rule_id (just remember them in a variable)

```
protected function _limitMaxDiscount($r, $rule, $itemId, $quote)
{
    if ($rule->getMaxDiscount()==0) {
        return $r[$itemId];
    }
    if (isset($this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()])) {
        $this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()]['base_discount'] += $r[$itemId]['base_discount'];
    } else {
        $this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()]['base_discount'] = $r[$itemId]['base_discount'];
    }
    if ($this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()]['base_discount'] > $rule->getMaxDiscount()) {
        $r[$itemId]['base_discount'] = $r[$itemId]['base_discount'] - ($this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()]['base_discount'] - $rule->getMaxDiscount());
        $r[$itemId]['discount'] = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice(
            $r[$itemId]['base_discount']
        );
    }
    return $r[$itemId];
}
```

4) when apply next discount to an item, check if it is in the range.

Comment: Where is the "handleValidation" function definition? please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Login to Admin panel > Promotions > Shopping cart price rules > than create new rules with below condition :

Steps : **General information**
[image]

**step 2** : conditions 
[image]

**step 3** : Actions
[image]

Apply "your coupon code" as coupon code in shopping cart page. also enter the discount amount under "Actions"

Please remove cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Magento 2, then there is a FREE extension that does the job:
https://www.magepsycho.com/magento2-discount-limiter.html

It allows setting the maximum discount amount (upper limit) for a percentage-based cart rule.

Logically,
It creates a plugin around `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\ByPercent`