# Magento - Shopping Cart Rules - Discount based on percentage (20%) - How to cap?

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, promotions

Is there a way I can resrict the maximum amount for percentage discount?

#### Example 1 :

20% off discount for any SKU. So let say the SKU price is $1,000 - 20% off = $980  [ final Price = $980 , not $800 ]

#### Example 2 :

Product price = $20, discount(20%) = $4 discount.

- customer can enjoy only 20 $ as discount

Comment: Good catch @fschmengler , seems you know  all 40,000 questions & answers in this community.....

Comment: Credits go to @Pawel below ;)

Answer (score 1):

go to `Promotions > shopping cart price rules` , **Under conditions**  use as below image.

[image]

**Under Actions**

[image]

Under **General information**  => **Select Websites , customer Groups**, you can set **coupon codes** if you want or give **No coupon** , you can set **Dates limit** within that period only this discount will apply , otherwise leave this as blank. Let me know if you find any Problems in this....

Comment: Thanks. This seems not applicable for my case.

Comment: Let me put it this way....

Discount = 20% off
SKU price = $1000
Discount = $200

^Can I limit it that customers can only enjoy the discount amount up to $20 (I cap it) - so that Customer needs to pay $980

Another example : 
Discount = 20% off
SKU price = $2000
Discount = $400

^Can I limit it that customers can only enjoy the discount amount up to $20 (I cap it) - so that customer needs to pay $1980 ?

Thanks :))

Comment: @jester means do you want to give 20 $ only discount ?  or you want to give 20 % discount only but maximum discount that should apply is 20 $  ?

Comment: @jester do you want to give 20 $ for entire cart/subtotal or 20 $ discount for  each products ?

Comment: Hi Baby. I wanna give 20% discount off but wanna cap it as in....out of the 20% discount - customer can only enjoy maximum $20. Example A : Product price = $20, discount(20%) = $4. Example B : Product price = $120, discount(20%) = $20 (maximum)

Comment: this is for entire cart/subtotal. Thanks

Comment: This seems to be very tricky, i dont think default magento provide this solution of restricting `maximum amount of discount to 20 $` , let me check once more. also I edited question....

Comment: @jester you can folow this link : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87751/maximum-discount-percent-magento

Comment: Thanks! it seems  i gotta ask my developers to do something w the coding.....

Comment: @jester Thats better, please accept the answer once your developers found solution with above link....

Answer (score 0):

There is already a good answers:
[Maximum discount percent magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87751/maximum-discount-percent-magento)

Summery: no, it's not possible with the Magento Core. You can create your own function.

3
down vote
Surprisingly, this is not possible in the Magento 1.x without an extension or code modification.

```
To add this feature in our module we had to:

1) add a new field max_discount in the table salesrule

2) observe event salesrule_validator_process

        <salesrule_validator_process>
        <observers>
            <amasty_rules_model_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>amrules/observer</class>
                <method>handleValidation</method>
            </amasty_rules_model_observer>
        </observers>
        </salesrule_validator_process>
3) keep track of all discounts given to item by rule_id (just remember them in a variable)

protected function _limitMaxDiscount($r, $rule, $itemId, $quote)
{
    if ($rule->getMaxDiscount()==0) {
        return $r[$itemId];
    }
    if (isset($this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()])) {
        $this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()]['base_discount'] += $r[$itemId]['base_discount'];
    } else {
        $this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()]['base_discount'] = $r[$itemId]['base_discount'];
    }
    if ($this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()]['base_discount'] > $rule->getMaxDiscount()) {
        $r[$itemId]['base_discount'] = $r[$itemId]['base_discount'] - ($this->_ruleDiscount[$rule->getId()]['base_discount'] - $rule->getMaxDiscount());
        $r[$itemId]['discount'] = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice(
            $r[$itemId]['base_discount']
        );
    }
    return $r[$itemId];
}
4) when apply next discount to an item, check if it is in the range.
```

Comment: If the question is already answered in another question, without further explanation, please close as duplicate instead of copying the other answer.